# Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 failed; installing the upgrades; preparing libco

Tags: 11.10

[Screenshot of Distribution Upgrade failure](http://i177.photobucket.com/albums/w206/StinkyToFu_SRO/Upgradehanging.png)
I had Ubuntu 11.10 installed in a virtual machine.  Attempted to upgrade it to 12.04 and it hung at Installing the upgrades/preparing libco.  Left it there all day.  Still able to navigate around it, but ultimately at the end of the day it still did not finish upgrading.  Attempted to reboot it and in return it just flickered during boot up.

system state frozen, preparing libco stuck, installing upgrades, 12.04

Reinstalling from scratch.

[image: http://i177.photobucket.com/albums/w206/StinkyToFu_SRO/Upgradehanging.png]

Answer (score 0):

Try updating from the command line.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to try to perform a release upgrade from the command line, or to try to fix (i.e., finish) an interrupted one? The former would be `sudo do-release-upgrade` and the latter would be `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (since finishing such an upgrade requires that some packages be newly installed and others removed, which `upgrade` will never do).